# Python: How to enable and disable functions?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class

I have a Raspberry Pi with an infrared sensor. Inside my Python script there is a threading class who listens to an imap server (catch instructions like START or STOP). My idea is now to send commands via email and as soon as the script received a command some functions should be disabled until a new command is received. But the main issue is now I don't know how to implement it.
Thank you for useful and helpful ideas.

```
def take_picture():
   ...

def take_video():
   ...

class EmailThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
         ....
                if get_mail == 1:
                    if var_subject == 'STOP':
                        #TODO: stop take_picture(), take_video()
                        pass

                    elif var_subject == 'START':
                  #TODO: start take_picture(), take_video()
                        pass
                    else:
                        print u'Wrong command'

         time.sleep(600) #google doesn't like many connections within 10min

def main():
    # Start eMail Thread
    email = EmailThread()
    email.start()
    try:
        print "Waiting for PIR to settle ..."
        # Loop until PIR output is 0
        while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR) == 1:
            Current_State = 0
        print "Ready"
        # Loop until threadingusers quits with CTRL-C
        while True :
            # Read PIR state
            Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)
            if Current_State == 1 and Previous_State == 0:
                counter = counter + 1
                # PIR is triggered
                start_time = time.time()

                log_to_file('Motion  Nr. %s detected!' % counter)
                take_picture()

                # Record previous state
                Previous_State = 1

            elif Current_State == 0 and Previous_State == 1:
                # PIR has returned to ready state
                stop_time=time.time()
                print "  Ready ",
                elapsed_time=int(stop_time-start_time)
                print " (Elapsed time : " + str(elapsed_time) + " secs)"
                Previous_State = 0

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Quit "
        # Reset GPIO settings
        GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I sugest using `python3`, unless you have a specific reason to use `python2`. Even if you decide to use `python2`, I suggest using `print` as a function.

Comment: I am using python2.7 because some moduls are running only under python2 like picamera

Comment: Do you look for some fancy architectural thing? I would just set a bool flag in the email thread and put an `if email.enable_picture:` in the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question title is badly chosen. I think what you're trying to do is start/stop *threads* that are running the functions. Starting a thread is easy enough, stopping it is slightly harder and depends on what the function internally does.

You'll want to look into inter-thread communication methods, especially `condition variables`. In general, a thread can only be gracefully stopped while it allows you to do so, for example while sleeping on a condition variable.

If you actually do not want to use threads, but instead *periodically* want to run the currently-active functions, you need to implement a scheduler - in the easiest case, the scheduler would simply repeatedly loop through the list of active functions, and invoke them.

I'd recommend the latter, as threads mostly just introduce unneeded complexity and error sources, but from your question it sounds like you're pretty determined to do the first.

Answer (score 2):

in init, you can add a map of functions refs to booleans, like so

```
class ClassWithTheFunctions:
    def __init__(self):
        import types
        #...
        self.funcMap = {}
        for o in self.__dict__:
            if type(self.__dict__[o]) == types.FunctionType or type(self.__dict__[o]) == types.MethodType:
                self.funcMap[self.__dict__[o]] = True
```

when you want to call a function , you check it first

```
 if instanceOfTheClassWithTheFunctions.funcMap[funcIWantToCall] :
     funcIWantToCall()
```

if you want to disable a function :

```
  instanceOfTheClassWithTheFunctions.funcMap[funcIWantToCall] = False
```

or enable it :

```
  instanceOfTheClassWithTheFunctions.funcMap[funcIWantToCall] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think self.enabled would work in this case ?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled=True        
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
```

and toggle enable to true / false ?

Comment: I recommend against creating answers in the shape of rhetoric questions. They risk being mistaken and flagged for being a new questions which you ask. Please rephrase into a more assertive answer.